# How to access JS object values with Dynamic keys in Forloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, for-loop, object

count defines the next available q series variables, from the code count is 2 so q8, q9 are available.
to extract variables of q series I'm printing as below

```
let inputdata = {count:{value:2}, q8:{value:'John'}, q9:{value:'Siva'}};
    for (let index = 1; index <= inputdata.count.value; index++) {
        let pos = 7+index;
        let q = `inputdata.q` + pos;
        console.log("Vals: ", q.value);
    }
```

Comment: for ... in and for ... of. Check the javascript documentation.

Comment: for....of works well as I have used it my project

Comment: You can just make it `let q = inputdata['q' + pos];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let inputdata = {count:{value:2}, q8:{value:'John'}, q9:{value:'Siva'}};
    for (let index = 1; index <= inputdata.count.value; index++) {
        let pos = 7+index;
        let q = 'q' + pos;
        console.log("Vals: ", inputdata[q]);
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.